# getting central table in webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have difficulties scraping data from a website: https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/?c=s&view=2

I would like to get the central table with the abstracts, but if I do

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/?c=s&view=2") 
page %>% html_table()
```

I only get a small empty table.

```
> page %>% html_table()
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  X1            X2
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 "version:"  1.02
2 ""         NA   
3 ""         NA   
4 ""         NA
```

It looks I am getting only the left side bar by doing so (trying `page %>%  html_text()` gives only left sidebar content).

I tried using `sessions`, but did not improve.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the URL copied from the address bar does not define the page that you had open in your browser -- those list links (and other controls) generate 2 requests, i.e. href `https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/index.cfm?view=2&c=si` triggers a view update at server side but returns empty response with a redirect to `/archiveeular/?c=s&view=2`, which in turn responds with the actual content. Accessing `/archiveeular/?c=s&view=2` directly, in a fresh session, delivers a different page.

So instead of `read_html()` you'd want to use something that handles redirections, preferably automagically, and can simulate browser session: `rvest::session()`

To get to the table and increase the number of items shown on the page, we need to jump through a series of URLs first and keep the session; parsing a `session()` result is the same as with `read_html()` result:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# run in session: open page, jump to "Abstract Titles", set page size to 100
s <- session("https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/index.cfm") |>
  session_jump_to("https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/index.cfm?view=2&c=si") |>
  session_jump_to("https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/calc.cfm?pagesize=100")

# extract page count 
page_count <- 
  s |>
  html_element("div.items-found > b:last-of-type") |> 
  html_text() |> 
  as.integer()
page_count
#> [1] 37

# extract table, handle duplicate column names and drop empty column
get_table <- function(s) {
  html_element(s, "table.table-result") |> 
    html_table() |>
    setNames(c("item", "title", "blank")) |>
    select(item, title)
}
# navigate to a new page
jump_page <- function(s, n){
  session_jump_to(s, paste0("https://scientific.sparx-ip.net/archiveeular/calc.cfm?page=",n))
}

# list allocation for tables
tables <- vector(mode = "list", length = page_count)

# table from current(1st) page
tables[[1]] <- get_table(s)

# collect tables from next 4 pages
for (n in 2:5){
  message("Page ", n)
  s <- jump_page(s, n)
  tables[[n]] <- get_table(s)
}
#> Page 2
#> Page 3
#> Page 4
#> Page 5

# concat tables from the list
bind_rows(tables)
```

Result :

```r
#> # A tibble: 500 × 2
#>    item              title                                                      
#>    <chr>             <chr>                                                      
#>  1 2023 POS0772      ´´EPIDEMIOLOGY OF JUVENILE IDIOPATHIC ARTHRITIS IN ARGENTI…
#>  2 2023 POS0147      αVβ3 INTEGRIN AS A LINKER BETWEEN FIBROSIS AND THYROID HOR…
#>  3 2023 OP0275-HPR   ‘IT’S A LOT TO TAKE IN’: A SYSTEMATIC REVIEW OF THE INFORM…
#>  4 2023 POS0175      “DO DISEASE MODIFYING ANTIRHEUMATIC DRUGS INFLUENCE THE FR…
#>  5 2023 AB1732-PARE  “FLARE, DID YOU SAY FLARE?” FLARES IN SJÖGREN’S DISEASE: T…
#>  6 2023 POS1447      “IF I HAVE SJÖGREN’S SYNDROME, I WANT TO KNOW IT AS EARLY …
#>  7 2023 AB0201       “IT SURPRISED ME A LOT THAT THERE IS A LINK”: A QUALITATIV…
#>  8 2023 POS0788-HPR  “IT’S LIKE LISTENING TO THE RADIO WITH A LITTLE INTERFEREN…
#>  9 2023 POS0201-PARE “MOOD IS HAPPY AND DOWNRIGHT WILD” - HEALTH PROMOTION AND …
#> 10 2023 POS1585-HPR  “SO, MEN WILL BE ABLE TO RECEIVE #METHOTREXATE FOR LUPUS A…
#> # ℹ 490 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Whaou @margusl, thanks for the explanation and the nice code chunk.